# Lenovo ThinkPad W540 works through the power adapter without the battery, but won't charge the battery

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad W540 that, once plugged in without a battery, works fine. However, when I connect the battery, it just won't charge.

In most cases connecting the adapter into the laptop, doesn't cause the LED to flash, which is a sign of charging. The battery did charge once for about 2 minutes before returning to this non-charge state.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a new battery? A replacement? You say “The battery did charge once for about 2 minutes…” but what does that mean? This laptop was released in 2013 so was this a refurbished purchase? Is the battery a replacement?

Comment: ... because if it is the original battery you can be certain it's dead.

Comment: The laptop has been with me for a while. The jack is fine, and the battery I recently bought is about 2 months old. Can't see a reason why it'd work without the battery, yet not charge

Comment: The laptop doesn't indicate that the battery is charging, but the battery doesn't go down. I'm constantly at 11 percent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of research and gained knowledge, I figured I'd let the laptop run on the false percentage indication of 13 percent. It would sooner or later run out and die, which it did. Now that it's truly at 0 percent, it works perfectly fine. All you have to do is let it die without the adapter.